# Vertical align middle text and image in link

Tags: html, css

Using the code below my text is vertically aligned bottom.  Need help vertical aligning the text middle with the icon in the link.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s15199ds/7AGjB/)

HTML

```
<a href="/The-Experience.aspx" class="icon">
    <span class="white bold">Learn More</span>
    <div class="arrow-white-right"></div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
a.icon { line-height:46px; vertical-align:middle; }
.arrow-white-right { display:inline-block; height:46px; width:46px; background:url('/img/icons/arrow-white-glyph.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:-50px 0; }
.white { color:#fff; }
.bold {font-weight:bold; }
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding position:absolute to your .arrow-white-right class.

Here a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/B4KC7/1/

```
.arrow-white-right { 
   position:absolute; 
   display:inline-block; 
   height:46px; width:46px; 
   background:url('/img/icons/arrow-white-glyph.png'); 
   background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:-50px 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `img` tag and give that the `vertical-align` property.

```
<img src="/img/icons/arrow-white-glyph.png" widtt="46" height="46"/>

<a href="/The-Experience.aspx" class="icon">
    Learn More
</a>

a.icon { 
    line-height:46px; 
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
}
img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I'm also not too sure why you're using a `<span>` to style your anchor tag. It seems a bit redundant.

[Here is a JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3YG9W/2/)